# Python: Generating from geometric distribution

Tags: python, numpy, random

Is this best way or most efficient way to generate random numbers from a geometric distribution with an array of parameters that may contain 0?

```
allids["c"]=[2,0,1,1,3,0,0,2,0]
[ 0 if x == 0 else numpy.random.geometric(1./x) for x in allids["c"]]
```

Note I am somewhat concerned about optimization.

EDIT:

A bit of context: I have an sequence of characters (i.e. ATCGGGA) and I would like to expand/contract runs of a single character (i.e. if original sequence had a run of 2 'A's I want to simulate a sequence that will have an expected value of 2 'A's, but vary according to a geometric distribution). All the characters that are runs of length 1 I do NOT want to be of variable length.

So if

```
seq = 'AATCGGGAA'
allids["c"]=[2,0,1,1,3,0,0,2,0]
rep=[ 0 if x == 0 else numpy.random.geometric(1./x) for x in allids["c"]]

"".join([s*r for r, s in zip(rep, seq)])
```

will output (when `rep` is `[1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0]`)

```
"ATCGGGA"
```

Comment: There are two mathematical definitions for the geometric distribution, the first (which Python implements) has support on strictly positive integers 1,2,3,... and represents the number of trials until first success, the second which has support on 0,1,2,... and represents the number of failures until first success. Can you give us some usage context of what the array really represents? If they're supposed to be means, the 0's are _a priori_ invalid. If they're realization outcomes, you should be using the second geometric form but need more data to estimate parameterization.

Comment: I'm aware of the different parameterizations of the geometric distribution. I added some context if you are still interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [masked array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) to avoid the division by zero.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ma.masked_equal([2, 0, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0], 0)
rep = np.random.geometric(1. / a)
rep[a.mask] = 0
```

This generates a random sample for each element of `a`, and then deletes some of them later. If you're concerned about this waste of random numbers, you could generate just enough, like so:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ma.masked_equal([2, 0, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0], 0)
rep = np.zeros(a.shape, dtype=int)
rep[~a.mask] = np.random.geometric(1. / a[~a.mask])
```

Comment: Great solutions guys, I knew I wasn't being as efficient by drawing random numbers individually.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
counts = array([2, 0, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0], dtype=float)
counts_ma = numpy.ma.array(counts, mask=(counts == 0))
counts[logical_not(counts.mask)] = \
    array([numpy.random.geometric(v) for v in 1.0 / counts[logical_not(counts.mask)]])
```

You could potentially precompute the distribution of homopolymer runs and limit the number of calls to `geometric` as fetching large numbers of values from RNGs is more efficient than individual calls